# Domain driven design: Aggregate forbidding references to its members

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregate

Following the DDD rules an aggregate should not allow external objects to hold references to its members.

If an aggregate "Invoice" is encapsulating an invoice and it's details. How should the aggregate Invoice provide the information so I can show the details or generate a report?

Comment: The principles of DDD tend to be most effective in collaborative domains where CQRS is also in order. Therefore, reporting from the same domain model you use for updates gets really messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of DDD holding a reference means a database reference of some sort. It does not mean that once you load your aggregate from the database nothing can obtain a runtime reference to any of its members. The idea is that all interactions with aggregate members go through the aggregate thereby fulfilling its role as a consistency and integrity boundary. For display and query purposes however, I prefer the [read-model pattern](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/25/read-models-as-a-tactical-pattern-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/) where a query specific class is used to represent query data and is distinct from the class used to represent the aggregate. This allows the aggregate to focus on its behavior without concern for how it may be queries. If using CQRS + [Event Sourcing](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/02/20/why-use-event-sourcing/), then you aggregate have no public data members, only behavior methods. In this case, queries are implemented as projections based on the events generated by the aggregate.

Comment: Thanks eulerfx. Though you are pointing to a good solution I think that it is not just about avoiding database references, but run-time references too. As you said the idea is that all interactions with aggregate members go through the aggregate thereby fulfilling its role as a consistency and integrity boundary. If I provide a reference to an internal entity, and there are public setters then I would be breaking the model.

Comment: Yes that is true and how strict you are in this regard can vary. For example if you are using an ORM such as NHibernate, it requires public members for mapping so you have no choice but to leave the option open for external references.

Comment: A database reference or detail such as ORM has no place in the Domain. THat's why you start modelling the domain IGNORING the database, so that you won't be tempted to build everything db centric. CQRS is the obvious, simplest and maintainable solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I allow clients to hold references to Value Objects. I return VO's without fear. I also pass VO's to public methods on the Aggregate Root. Value Objects are immutable and therefor there is no danger of outside state change that would violate the Aggregate's consistency boundary.